# Chart framework for both images and browser-based charts

Tags: php, javascript, image, browser, charts

I'm well aware of a large number of chart rendering frameworks, some Javascript (like Google Chart, ThreeD, HighCharts), PHP based ones like jpGraph and pChart and online REST API's like Google's old chart tools (to disappear in 2015).

All of them seem to specialize in one particular "flavour" of graph; either rendered images or browser-based graphs using SVG, Canvas, Flash or such. I'd like to be able to present a report both in the browser and exported as a printable PDF. Converting static HTML to PDF can be done using a number of frameworks (I prefer mPDF) so that won't be a problem.

What I'd like is a single framework that is able to generate graphs both as images and browser-based. Obviously they should be compatible with a wide range of browsers and the graphs should look similar (not necessarily identical). Preferable using PHP and/or JS, but I'm open to suggestions.

Does anybody know a single chart framework that can render both to images and browser-based?

If there are multiple frameworks with nearly identical API's and graphs, that would be good too, but I doubt such a combination exists. ;)

Comment: You must choose between JS graph and Image one. JS is informative, but uncovertable to pdf\doc source. Images are convertable.. but static. I dont see any other solutions as to make two different outputs for generating doc\pdf in png and displaying page to user in html+js

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any library which is able to render a bitmap and a svg or canvas, supporting all the graph and drawing features.

If I had this problem, I would take a serious look into phantomjs:

http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart

It is a headless browser which can render bitmaps or even PDF. The advantage is, that you just have to develop the browser based rendering and phantomjs could take the job of rendering the images.

Comment: Good idea. Never occured to me to use a headless browser's output, even though I've used the somewhat similar wkhtmltopdf (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) in the past.